# Orbiting an object in Vuforia using c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have written a simple script in c# for Unity to make a 3D object like sphere orbit (0,0,0) above  image target.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    float angles;
    float radiuss;
    float angleSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        angles = 0;
        radiuss = 0.2f;
        angleSpeed = 1;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        angles += Time.deltaTime * angleSpeed;


        float x = radiuss * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angles);
        float z = radiuss * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angles);
        float y = 1*0;

        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

The script works fine if not used for Vuforia, but when I add it to an object for Vuforia it acts weird and doesn't follow the path as described by the script.

These are the configurations and hierarchy.
[image]

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your vuforia config how the center of the world is affected. I think it's in the AR Camera, you have a component "Vuforia Behaviour". And you have a parameter "World Center Mode". By default it's your device:

[image]

This means that your camera is the origin at all times, so, when you move your phone or your camera in real world, it's actualy the objects that moves (their position according to the camera changes) in the "unity world".

Try to change :

```
transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

into :

```
transform.localposition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```